# How to get an element in each loop of gridview in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want to get the IdQueue's of the Queues I have checked in the check box, in java script.
For example, if i have checked boxes of IdQueue's 3 and 5, i want that the JS will alert me the IdQueue of them.

I need your help with this JS.

Thanks ahead.

```html
    <div data-role="popup" align=center id="Div1" style="width:600px; height:400px; direction:rtl; background-color:white">

                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                OnRowCommand="grd_Threshold_Command" CssClass="text" Width="80%" OnRowDataBound="grd_Threshold_OnRowDataBound" >
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="gridRow" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IdQueue" Visible="true">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCSQCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CSQid") %>' BorderStyle="none"
                                BorderWidth="0px"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NameQueue" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCSQName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' BorderStyle="none"
                                BorderWidth="0px"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IntervalQueue" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList Visible="true" Enabled="true" ID="ddlResalution" EnableViewState="true"
                                runat="server" Width="148px">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ChooseQueue" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbk1"  runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMust" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <div style="width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/glossyGreenOK.gif"
                    Height="40px" OnClick="lnkBranchReport_Click" Width="40px" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;color: #003399; font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 14px;">
                
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnbSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="CheckedBoxes()" >ok</asp:LinkButton>
               
            </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: function CheckedBoxes() {
            var gv = document.getElementById("GridView1");
            var inputList = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
  
            var rowss = gv.rows;
            var id=0;           
            for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
                if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i].checked) {
                                                        
                    var cell = rowss[i].cells[0];
                    alert(cell);
                }
            }                                      
        }
But its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbk1"  runat="server" EnableViewState="true" data-id='<%# Eval("CSQid") %>' />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnbSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="CheckedBoxes();return false();" >ok</asp:LinkButton>
```

Add a custom attribute to checkbox so we can directly access id from here instead getting from label `lblCSQCode`. After that add this javascript

> First way

```
 $('#<%=lnbSave.ClientID%>').on('click', function() {
     var arr = [];
     var selectedID = '';
     $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
         var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
         arr.push(id);    
     });
     selectedID = arr.join();
     //alert(selectedID);
 });
```

---

> Second way

```
function CheckedBoxes() {
    var arr = [];
    var selectedID = '';
    $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
        arr.push(id);    
    });
    selectedID = arr.join();
    //alert(selectedID);
}
```

Comment: I have this error:
"Two-way binding is only supported for properties. 'data-id' is not a valid property on 'CheckBox' "

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error Message: Two-way binding is only supported for properties. 'data-id' is not a valid property on 'CheckBox'

Line 246:                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbk1"  runat="server" EnableViewState="true" data-id='<%# Bind("CSQid") %>'/>

Comment: Instead of Bind()  please try Eval(). Bind() method only applies to C# properties all the more there are few changes in my code I'm updating them too.

Comment: Thank you. It's helped.
Now I have this error:
"Server Error in '/' Application"
-Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'CLientID' and no extension method 'CLientID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

    Line 54:      $('#<%=GridView1.CLientID%> tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {

Comment: So sorry, it's ClientID not CLientID. Have updated my code please check.

Comment: If everything is working properly and you are able to get the checkbox id's then you can mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: @David: Thanks a lot :)